# If $f$ is strictly convex prove that $f(x + f'(x)) \geq f(x)$ for every $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$(maps from $R$ to $R$) be twice differentiable function and strictly convex. Prove that for every $x$ from $R$ it is true that $f(x + f'(x))\geq f(x)$.

Let's suppose otherwise i.e. let $c$ be such that $f(c + f'(c))<f(c)$. We have that $f$ is strictly convex if and only if $f'$ is strictly increasing. Now let $f$ reach it's minimum in $l$ i.e. $f'(l)=0$. Since $f'$ is strictly increasing it is also strictly increasing on $(l,\infty)$. Now since $f'(x)>0$ for every $x$ from $(l,\infty)$ it follows that for every $x,y$ from $(l,\infty)$, where $x<y$ we have that $f(x)<f(y)$. So if $c$ is from $(l,\infty)$ we have that $c + f'(c) > c$ but $f(c + f'(c))<f(c)$, that is contradiction. We do almost same process from $(-\infty,l)$. If $f$ doesn't have a minimum it means that $f'(x)$ is either $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for whole domain. Let $f'(x)>0$ for whole domain. This means that $f$ is strictly increasing on whole domain  i.e. if $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$. Since $c + f'(c) > c$ and we have that $f(c + f'(c))<f(c)$ we reach a contradiction. We do almost same process for $f'(x)<0$. Hence it follows that for every $x$ from $R$ it is true that  $f(x + f'(x))\geq f(x)$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Did Let $f$(maps from $R$ to $R$) be twice differentiable function and stirctly convex. Porve that for ever $x$ from $R$ it is true that $f(x+f′(x))≥f(x)$

Comment: And the answer starts at "Let's suppose otherwise" and ends at "Hence it follows that (f)or every $x$ from $R$ it is t(ru)e that  $f(x + f'(x))\geq f(x)$", no?

Comment: @Did Yes, thats where it starts(answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think there is any mistake :)

But you can can show this  more nicely/rigorously by use of Lagrange mean value theorem .
Indeed,

Suppose $f'(x) >0$ for some $x$ then, 
Applying LMVT to interval , $[x,x+f'(x)]$, we have, 
$$ f(x+f'(x))-f(x) =  f'(a)f'(x) $$ 
Now , since $a \in (x,x+f'(x)$, $f'(a)>f'(x)>0$ Thus, 
$f(x+f'(x)) > f(x) $.

Do the same, assuming $f'(x) <0$ for some $x$.
And when $f'(x)=0$, this relation is obviously true (equality case)